# Protecting drop down fields values from being altered

Tags: php, html, wordpress, forms, gravity-forms-plugin

Am using drop down field to show user country in the front end,and i want to know if is possible for hackers or user to change or alter the values i set in the drop down list?
Secondly, is their any known tools or script that a user can use to edit a read only fields?

Comment: You can't protect the client side... you need to check everything on the server side.

Comment: essentially NOTHING in the browser is safe from manipulation. Any HTML you have can be tweaked - with forms you can, in many cases, entirely bypass the form on the webpage and target the endpoint ( action ) using curl or other technique. Any validation applied client-side can be avoided so it is a hindrance at most to those up to no good. It is the serverside code that needs to be strengthened.

Comment: valid question, for many of us it seems basic, but is highly valuable for many people out there.

Answer (score 1):

It's actually pretty simple to change values using your chrome developer tools. You can just right click --> inspect --> change any value you want. You can't stop people editing what they get to see.

So this means that if you send a dropdown with items:

- Belgium
- France
- Netherlands

It is very easy for a user to change those values to 3 different countries and submit these values. There is nothing you can do about that.

What you should do is check the submitted values. Your server can 'remember' the values that he has send and should check if the submitted values are one of the send values. If not you know that the client has changed his values.

Comment: After editing it on fronted and they hit submit will the form submit their new values to me against the ones i set originally in the drop down field?

Comment: @pandglobal - in answer to your question - "Yes"

Comment: Then i think i have a serious problem,  because some values am using is autopopulated from the user meta value, and am using gravity form. And this is huge floop if the value be changed from the user end.

Comment: Is there any server side php functions that be used to validate this.? Especially related to gravity forms

Comment: Use a database to store user side information. On submit check with database for validation of the request. I'm not very familiar with php/website stuff so I can't help you with specific code sorry.